# retrieve data from database with checkbox and submit it again with checked data using javascript , html or in servlet

Tags: javascript, servlets

I'm working on attendance register system project. So I retrieve students name and roll no from student  table with checkbox but I have no idea how to submit again it with the checked data.

Comment: Using JQuery you can send an Ajax request on checkbox checked and handle this data update in the database

Comment: I have no idea about JQuery.can I solve it using javascript.

Comment: You can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API BUT JQuery is a simple  javascript library it is making the things easy to send an ajax request you can check the JQuery docs here : https://api.jquery.com/